How to convert a Queue to a Vec in Rust?
How to convert a queues::Queue to a Vec in Rust? Am I missing something obvious since a Queue is implemented as Vec underneath.
I did consider just using Vec, but it lacks a pop_front method. I also considered using a VecDeque but then I still don't don't know how to convert it to a Vec.
As to why I want to do something like this, I need to convert a Queue to a Vec so I can use String::from_utf8 on it. Basically I'm processing a sequence of ASCII characters in FIFO order, I need to store them somehow and then convert them to a String.

Note that finding a library on crates.io is no guarantee of its quality. As crates.io has no entry bar, it contains a wide array of projects, ranging from highest-quality ones maintained by the Rust team to amateurish ones like the one you found, and even scammy/malicious ones. Before using a crate, be sure to check alternatives, and consult sites with recommendations like this one.

The library you're using has numerous issues, mainly that the data structure they're using is not a proper queue. Their remove method is just calling remove(0) on the internal Vec. It also has no way to convert the data into Vec besides popping every element one by one.
Use VecDeque. You can convert a VecDeque to Vec using into or from using this impl.
let vec_deque = VecDeque::new();
let vec: Vec<_> = vec_deque.into();

// or
let vec_deque = VecDeque::new();
let vec = Vec::from(vec_deque);


This is an XY problem.
Converting a VecDeque is overkill for your given use case.  Just push each character onto a Vec<u8> and then reverse the Vec before calling String::from_utf8().
let mut bytes = vec![];

// Push onto bytes...

bytes.reverse();

let string = String::from_utf8(bytes).unwrap();

This has better performance characteristics than the VecDeque approach: reverse() is O(n) just as iterating a VecDeque is, however it will not require creating any new allocations.
Additionally, if you know how many bytes you will be pushing in advance, you can use Vec::with_capacity() to preallocate exactly the right size buffer.
